# Usage of the '"of"

Tags: prepositions

Sometimes I have trouble understanding a sentence which begins with "of" and I find it a bit senseless. Let me show some examples:

1. Of the exposure to the disease, it takes about 2 weeks for the first symptoms to appear.
2. Of the all thing i have ever seen, the grand canyon is the most amazing.
3. Of the ten thousand units made in 1988, ten percent were sold in Europe.

Would you please explain how the "of" works in the beginning of a sentence? Are there any rules that the "of" is used like so? Please give me the meanings of the sentences which I typed above. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: 'The Grand Canyon is the most amazing of all the natural wonders I have ever seen.' may be re-ordered: 'Of all the natural wonders I have ever seen, the Grand Canyon is the most amazing.' // 'Ten percent of the ten thousand units made in 1988 were sold in Europe.' may be re-ordered: 'Of the ten thousand units made in 1988, ten percent were sold in Europe.' // Sentence 1 is unacceptable.

Comment: #1 looks like a mistranscription of ***After** exposure...*

Comment: ive got it right. thank you all. and below what can be an answer to this question ' after exposure to the disease, it takes about to weeks for the first symptoms..............? 1-to appear 2- to be treated 3-to cure 4- to spread..?

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence doesn’t make any sense to me —
are you sure it wasn’t “After exposure to the disease, …”? 
For the others, just try moving the “of” phrase to later in the sentence.

- The Grand Canyon is the most amazing of the all things I have ever seen.
- Ten percent of the ten thousand units made in 1988 were sold in Europe.

This is just one example of the many ways that pieces of English sentences
can (sometimes) be rearranged. 
For example, “I whistle while I work” = “While I work, I whistle.” 
Speakers/writers can do this to manipulate the focus of the sentence. 
For example, if you wanted to emphasize that ten percent were sold in Europe,
you might prefer to have “ten percent” and “were sold in Europe”
next to each other, and not at opposite ends of the sentence. 
Also, one might want to avoid the
“Ten percent of the ten thousand” construction
because of the way it puts two numbers near each other.

Answer (score -1):

I had a look online, and according to talkenglish.com 
http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx

This is what I found, I hope this helps!!!

**Used for belonging to, relating to, or connected with:**

The secret of this game is that you can’t ever win.

The highlight of the show is at the end.

The first page of the book describes the author’s profile.

Don’t touch it. That’s the bag of my friend’s sister.

I always dreamed of being rich and famous.

**Used to indicate reference:**

I got married in the summer of 2000.

This is a picture of my family.

I got a discount of 10 percent on the purchase.

**Used to indicate an amount or number:**

I drank three cups of milk.

A large number of people gathered to protest.

I had only four hours of sleep during the last two days.

He got a perfect score of 5 on his writing assignment.

Comment: This answer is [plagiarised](http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx): please see our [help on referencing](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While corroboration from sources is valuable, we expect some sort of original work in editorial gloss rather than just copying.

Comment: oh sorry, I hadnt seen it like that, I will do something about it straight away!!